# Not showing dropdown menu, and "Nothing Selected" message showing in title, please check code

Tags: javascript, java, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

[image]

I'm trying to do auto select the option in dropdown menu but it is not showing dropdown menu and displaing title="Nothing Selected". In my code I have written `opt.setAttribute("selected", "selected");`

Comment: After you have read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question come back and edit your question. After this I'm sure you will get an answer.

Comment: Please remove the `java` tag in your question as [JavaScript Is Not Java](http://javascriptisnotjava.com)

Comment: Please give your code so that it can be checked / improved / corrected. You need to explain better what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

To set the option as selected you only need selected not selected="selected".